# Problem with Java Spring Boot - "Cannot convert from String to String [ ]"

Tags: java, string, spring-boot, api, type-conversion

I am trying to use a external API, but it´s returning an error that I am not understanding.

[Here is the code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhVuc.png)

Acessing the API - (https://swapi.dev/) - Here is my controller
[Where the problem is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8C3Q8.png)

Comment: you should put your codes to here as text instead of image

Comment: Just put the code inline here.  

To answer your question, I'm not sure what more you want from the compiler.  Your member variable 'characters' is defined as a String, not an array of Strings.  Your getter returns a String, not an array of Strings.  But then you are calling it and trying to assign the result to an array.  

If you want 'characters' to be an array, you not only have to define it and it's getter to be such, but also probably don't want a simple setter. You'd most likely want addCharacter(String character) which can be called multiple times to build up the array.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, looks like you are trying to assign a `String` (type of string) value to a variable declared as `String[]` (type of array of strings).

you define the following class

```
public class Filme {

    //... other attributes
    private String characters;
    //...

    // the following getter returns an `String` which is correct because attribute
    // `character` is declared as a `String`
    public String getCharacters() {
        return characters;
    }
    //... other setters and getters

}
```

and then when you get an array of `Filme`s from a service, you are trying to assign the attribute `characters` (String) to a variable `personagens` (String[])

```
// personagens is of type `String[]` (array of String) 
// mean while `filme.getCharacters()` return a `String` (a String)
String[] personagens = filme.getCharacters()
```

based on the [docs for the endpoint that you are consuming](https://swapi.dev/documentation#films), it says that `characters` is an `array`. So, it's ok to get that attribute as an String, when you try to deserialize from json to an object, but in the logic applied, you are trying to iterate over that. So, I think what you really want to do is change the type of `characters` attribute from `String` to `String[]`. After that you would need to fix the return type of the getter for that attribute

Comment: I think I understand, but it didn´t work. I did this:  <br/> String[] characters = new String[100];  <br/>public String[] getCharacters() { <br/>
   return characters;<br/>
  }<br/>

  public void setCharacters(String[] characters) {<br/>
   this.characters = characters;<br/>
  }  String[] personagens = filme.getCharacters();<br/>

Comment: Now it´s returning status 404 not found on Postman

Comment: Just with a 404 from postman is hard to know. What is returning the service? Did you log some message about what is returning the third party service? Instead of posting screenshots of your code, it would help that you use the correct formatting for code or post your project in a public repo